# Android ImageView Landscape - Portrait

Tags: android, xml

I have a simple application with ImageView

I need image to take all width and scroll y if it doesnt fit.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:id="@+id/myPic"
        android:contentDescription="@string/page_label" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything is perfect, but when i switch to landscape image wont take all width, there are blank spaces (left, right).

only ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_CROP helps, but it cuts piecies from top and bottom.
Is it possible make it work the same way in landscape?

Comment: Try adding android:fillViewPort="true" to your ScrollView

Comment: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fillViewPort' in package 'android'

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Comment: still it wont go width: 100% :(

Comment: try removing the RelativeLayout, Meanwhile, I got this, Note: If the application targets API level 17 or lower, adjustViewBounds will allow the drawable to shrink the view bounds, but not grow to fill available measured space in all cases. This is for compatibility with legacy MeasureSpec and RelativeLayout behavior.

Comment: Did u get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

scaletype `fitCenter` for the ImageView does the trick. It scales the picture to full width, and allows height to be scrolled while still maintaining aspect ratio.